# Text visibility problem while background image is changing time to time

Tags: html, css, asp.net

```
<asp:Image ID="image6" runat="server" />
<h4 class="pt-20">
<asp:Label ID="label6" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="Inherit" ></asp:Label>
</h4>
```

I set white color for label and label displays on top of the image. image is changed frequently according to server update. So when image is dark then text looks good but when it is light, text is not clearly visible. What to do so it works for any image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some visual technique I name it text border. For white text, use a black border to separate it from around environment:

```
#label6{
color: white;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a background with some transparency:

```
#label6 {
  display:inline-block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  color: #fff;
  padding:8px 10px;
}
```